# FormArray TypeError: value.forEach is not a function

Tags: angular, formbuilder

Why do I keep getting this error? I think I'm doing everything right?

"EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: value.forEach is not a function
TypeError: value.forEach is not a function at FormArray.setValue"

Component Class:

```
jobDetails: FormGroup;
techFormArray: FormArray;

constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder){

    this.techFormArray = new FormArray([
        new FormControl(''),
        new FormControl(''),
        new FormControl('')
    ]);
    this.jobDetails = this.formBuilder.group({
        techs: this.formBuilder.array([])
    });
    this.jobDetails.setValue({
        techs: this.techFormArray
    });
}
```

HTML:

```
<form [formGroup]="jobDetails">
  <div formArrayName="techs" >
    <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column">
      <div *ngFor="let tech of techFormArray.controls; let i=index">
        <md-checkbox [formControlName]="i">
          {{i}}
        </md-checkbox>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

SOLUTION:

FunStuff had it right, I couldn't use setValue.... so I removed it. Problem solved lol. I changed around a few things, and I'm not sure exactly what I did, it was essentially brute-force trial and error for hours, but then it worked! :)

Here's the working version!

```
jobDetails: FormGroup;

constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder){

    this.jobDetails = formBuilder.group({
        techs: formBuilder.array([
            formBuilder.control(''),
            formBuilder.control('')
        ])
    });
}
```

New HTML:

```
    <form [formGroup]="jobDetails">
        <div formArrayName="techs" >
            <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column">
                <div *ngFor="let tech of jobDetails.controls.techs.controls; let i=index">
                    <md-checkbox [formControlName]="i">
                        {{i}}
                    </md-checkbox>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: were is the for each function in your code.. some where you are trying to control.value.foreach funtion

Comment: something like this : - `this.techFormArray.value.forEach(() => {/**/}`

Comment: That's the component causing the error. I didn't tell it to use a loop, but I think FunStuff's answer might be why. I'll check it out today.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The **setValue** method takes simple values:

```
   this.techFormArray = new FormArray([
        new FormControl(''),
        new FormControl(''),
        new FormControl('')
    ]);

    this.jobDetails = this.formBuilder.group({
        techs: this.techFormArray
    });

    this.jobDetails.setValue({
      techs: ['a', 'b', 'c']
    });
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't think it mattered so I didn't include it, but in this scenario I threw in three mock values, in reality I actually don't know the values. I wanted to push them into the array as needed. How do we setValue if we don't know the size of the array?

Comment: Just push new FormControl.  this.techFormArray.push(new FormControl(''))

Comment: @FunStuff can you explain it please,  this.techFormArray.push(new FormControl(''))

Comment: i have it like this, this.customerForm = this.fb.group({
      home: '',
      addresses: this.fb.array([this.buildAddress()])
    }); and want to update addresses values in loop

Answer (score 0):

Since you are doing this in constructor. Else you would need to consider emptying the FormArray.

```
this.techFormArray.forEach((item, idx) => this.jobDetails.get('techs').setControl(idx, item));
```